# forms.CharField chokes on positional argument from in Django 1.6

Tags: django

Following code was valid until Django 1.5:

```
from django import forms
f = forms.CharField('f')
```

From 1.6 onwards this is invalid and results in following message:

```
File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 202, in __init__
   self.validators.append(validators.MaxLengthValidator(int(max_length)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'f'
```

The django documentation does not explain positional arguments back to v1.2. I need to upgrade code that has constructs like (which is also found in many examples in the Internet):

```
sender = forms.EmailField('sender', label=_(u'Sender'))
```

What is the function of the literal argument in the first position? Could it be an initial value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every field type is different. For a `CharField` (and also `EmailField` since it inherits from `CharField`), the first parameter is `max_length`.

I don't know why you say that was valid before Django 1.5. Looking back at the code before 1.5, that should have been invalid then too.

Maybe you are thinking of a model field? For model fields, most of the time, the first parameter is the `verbose_name`, in which case, `f = models.CharField('f')` would make sense.

Comment: The code that I used to demonstrate the behavior should clarify that I was testing forms fields, not model fields.
max_length is a kwarg, so it does not have a position. The __init__ of fileds does not have this.

The difference between djagno 1.5 and 1.6 could be casued that from 1-6 on CharField's __init__ calls the MaxLengthValidator with int(max_length). Before 1.6. it took max_length as is.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a kwarg, but it also has a position. look at the `__init__1 method for CharField: `def __init__(self, max_length=None, min_length=None, *args, **kwargs):` Doing this: `forms.CharField('f')` Would clearly set `'f'` to `max_length`.

Comment: Before 1.6, it did just pass max_length as is. But that still clearly does make any sense to pass a string to it. Even though it didn't fail before, it was still not "correct".

Comment: Aha, the first kwarg becomes the positional argument if being called.

Comment: Thanks, so the conclusion is that the various examples with forms.CharField('field') are just wrong, but have been ignored by Django so far.

Comment: That is correct. I don't know why those examples said that.